# Firebase Server Key HIDE

Tags: java, decompiler

I'm using android studio Java, I created a chat app and everything is working fine including Firebase Push Notification, but before I upload my app to playstore I need to hide my Server key from code for security reason, to protect my code from reverse engineer and decompiler. Is there's any tutorial on how to secure my Server key?

I used proguard, but I know my my server key still not safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can secure your `ApiKey` in `Android Studio`. This is not 100% secure way but this makes too much difficult to get `ApiKey` in Reverse Engineering. (Source: [videoUrl](https://youtu.be/-2ckvIzs0nU))

**Step 1:** add this code in `build.gradle(Module:app)`

```
android {
namespace 'com........fire'
compileSdk 33

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com...........fire"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"


    //Step:1 below code for hide API KEY
    Properties properties= new Properties();
    properties.load(project.rootProject.file("local.properties").newDataInputStream());
    buildConfigField "String","API_KEY_DBNAME","\"${properties.getProperty("API_KEY_DBNAME")}\""
    //now add value of this ApiKey in > local.properties(SDK Location) file<<
}
```

**Step 2:** add in `local.properties(SDK Location)` [set your ApiKey/Url/Firebase Database Name that you want to hide]

```
# Location of the SDK. This is only used by Gradle.
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk

#Step:2 add your API url here
API_KEY_DBNAME=dbTwoInput
```

**Now get your Api key anywhere in Java file (Before getting value just `Rebuild` your project**

```
String apiKeyDbName= BuildConfig.API_KEY_DBNAME;
```

[image]

> Edit: If you still not able to get string in your project then just add or check these two things
> [image]
> and also check
> [image]